# Azure Ad B2C - How B2c Checks if user is already signed in?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm creating a POC using adb2c mfa flow inside an iFrame.

The idea is to be shure that the user signed in can proof that he is the one making some critical changes inside the application.

As I'm doing this inside an iFrame, I can't really figure out how can I make B2C knows the user is already signed in inside the iframe, without the need to put credentials.

Executing the flow adding credentials is working smooth. But I need some enlightening on how to relief the user from inputing his credentials again.

The idea is to make it the safest way as possible. Any guess??

Cheers!

Comment: What is the reason behind using an iframe ?

Comment: Hi Thomas, the reason is to provide better user experience. I need to authenticate user data transaction with thirdy part application in a complex scenario with to many stps already, so I keep other required steps state while user authorize data transfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer you to follow the iframe support with Azure B2C with limitation using this below document.

Reference: -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/embedded-login?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

However, it is still in preview mode.

> > I need some enlightening on how to relief the user from inputing his credentials again.

Are you looking for SSO  with iframe?

Comment: In fact we are managing the risks and caveats of using iframes but we are pushing some limits in the same way. But for now it's all for POC.
I think SSO is what I'm looking for indeed. Some of these concepts are new to me and I don't have a clear vision where B2C looks for the session info. I know about cookies, but the fact that the iFrame will be considered a thirdy part / or not same origin, I'm trying to deal with some sort of safe mode to avoid inputing credentials again for better user xp. Thanx for answering!

Comment: Thanks and please find below document mentioned Session concepts with Azure B2C. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#session-behavior-properties